# How to set LineChartView's x axis values

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I'm using the [Swift Charts API](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to plot data taken with the iOS accelerometer. I simply need to plot the acceleration values on the y axis, and the time values on the x axis.

I managed to draw a line chart by providing the x and y values:

```
    lineChartView.delegate = self
    lineChartView.descriptionText = "Acceleration/Time"
    lineChartView.descriptionTextColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    lineChartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    let allData = ActivityData.getByActivitiesId(activity.id)

    var xVals = [String]()
    var yVals = [ChartDataEntry]()

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 3

    var i = 0;
    for data in allData
    {
        let entry = ChartDataEntry(value: data.xUserAcc, xIndex: i)
        yVals.append(entry)
        xVals.append(formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double:data.time))!)
        print(data.time)
        i += 1
    }

    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals, label: "xAcc")
    set1.axisDependency = .Left
    set1.setColor(UIColor.redColor())
    set1.setCircleColor(UIColor.redColor()) // our circle will be dark red
    set1.lineWidth = 2.0
    set1.circleRadius = 6.0 // the radius of the node circle
    set1.fillAlpha = 65 / 255.0
    set1.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    set1.highlightColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true

    let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: xVals, dataSets: [set1])
    lineChartData.setValueTextColor(UIColor.blackColor())
    lineChartView.data = lineChartData
```

But the problem is that x axis values are just used as labels to be shown on the x axis, but the intervals are not based on the actual x values that I provide. Let's explain this better with an image:

[image]

Like you see the values on the x are 3.89, 3.93 and 3.94. And they're shown at equal distance on the x axis even if between 3.89 and 3.93 there's a 0.04 gap, which is 4 times the gap between the second and third value. When I take data with the accelerometer I can't get it at a constant rate, so I need to specify the x values to the LineChartView but so far I couldn't find a way.